# Copy **cell FORMATS** from User Form to Datasheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to copy **cell FORMATS** from User Form to Datasheet
I have a script that works well in submitting from user form sheet to Datasheet and
Retrieving (search) from Datasheet to Userform.
Now, Please help me to copy  CELL FORMATS (like bold, text alignment, border, text/bg color) from UserForm to Datasheet again from Datasheet to UserForm using a search number

Linked two spreadsheets with actual data (Userform and Datasheet) for your reference

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NY_ckzEWxU7DCGro5tTqzpiOi6iG5PAQFxpZg0OKodY/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QL0jaNts2YRkZTlxmS0bk7V1fVVHBsJFmxS5C05PEmA/edit?usp=sharing

```
function submitdata() {
  const dstSpreadsheetId = "1QL0jaNts2YRkZTlxmS0bk7V1fVVHBsJFmxS5C05PEmA"; // Please set the destination Spreadsheet ID (WB-DataSheet_B).
  const dstSheetName = "DataSheet";
  const srcSheetName = "UserForm";

  // Retrieve values from source sheet and create an array and search value.
  const srcSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ranges = ["C3", "C7", "C8", "D8", "D6", "D4", "E8", "E19", "E20", "E21", "E22", "B10", "C10", "D10", "E10", "B11", "C11", "D11", "E11", "B12", "C12", "D12", "E12", "B13", "C13", "D13", "E13", "B14", "C14", "D14", "E14", "B15", "C15", "D15", "E15", "B16", "C16", "D16", "E16", "B17", "C17", "D17", "E17", "B18", "C18", "D18", "E18", "B19", "C19", "B20", "C20", "B21", "C21", "B22", "C22","D19", "D20", "D21", "D22"];
  const [search, ...values] = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(srcSpreadsheet.getId(),{ ranges: ranges.map(r => `'${srcSheetName}'!${r}`) }).valueRanges.flatMap(({ values, range }) => {
  if (range.includes("B10:E18")) return values ? values.flat() : [];
  if (range.includes("B19:D22")) return values ? values.flat() : [];
  return values ? values[0][0] : "";
});
if (!search) return;

  // Put the array to the destination sheet using the search value.
  const dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dstSpreadsheetId).getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  const range = dstSheet.getRange("A2:A" + dstSheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(search).findNext();
  if (range) {
    dstSheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 2, 1, values.length).setValues([values]);
  } else {
    dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, values.length + 1).setValues([[search, ...values]]);
  }
}
```

I have two spreadsheets with actual data (Userform and Datasheet) for your reference

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NY_ckzEWxU7DCGro5tTqzpiOi6iG5PAQFxpZg0OKodY/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QL0jaNts2YRkZTlxmS0bk7V1fVVHBsJFmxS5C05PEmA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

- [.copyFormatToRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyformattorangesheet,-column,-columnend,-row,-rowend)

By adding this to a range you can set the target range to the exact font styles, borders, alignment and colors.

### Usage:

```
const range = sheetA.getRange(1, 1, 3, 1)
range.copyFormatToRange(sheetB, 1, 1, 3, 1)
```

### Example:

Copy DataSheet B1 format to UserForm B10:B22

```
dstSheetName.getRange(`B1`)
            .copyFormatToRange(srcSheet, 10, 2, 12, 1)
```

Comment: can you guide inserting .copyFormatToRange() 
to the above code. please

Comment: I can't find the logic in the colors/format of the sheets or the code to be honest. But I will update my answer with a better example.

Comment: The userform is the main sheet where all formats and inputs are done and submitted to the datasheet. and later when user wants to edit specific values, they will search a log number in B2 and retrieve data from DataSheet to User Form and edit specific values, and then hit submit. Currently, all the values are getting submitted perfectly, Now I need to get Cell Formats too